# Java XML removeChild not working?

Tags: java, xml, dom

Hello so i've looked this question up alot but I couldn't find a solution that worked. I'm basically trying to remove the "job" node as seen declared in line 7 and removed in line 13. There's 0 runtime errors but the node doesn't get removed.

```
NodeList rootNodes = xml.getElementsByTagName("jobs");
        Node rootNode = rootNodes.item(0);
        Element rootElement = (Element) rootNode;
        NodeList jobsList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("job");

        for (int i = 0; i < jobsList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node job = jobsList.item(i);
            Element jobElement = (Element) job;

            if(jobElement.getAttribute("id").equals(
            msgEvent.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ")[2]))
            {
                rootNode.removeChild(job);
                msgEvent.getChannel().sendMessage("Removed Job " + jobElement.getAttribute("id") + " (Summary: '" + jobElement.getAttribute("summary") + "')").complete();
            }
        }
```

Here's the XML

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<jobs>
    <job payment = "50000" poster="171048434529337344" collect = "asdf" id = "1" summary="asdfd" expires="5/10/18"> </job>
    <job payment = "10000" poster="171048434529337344" collect = "asdf" id = "2" summary="asdf" expires="5/10/18"> </job>
</jobs>
```

Comment: how do you know that the node doesn't get removed? I tried your code and the node does get removed. that is, of course, if `msgEvent` contains an id that is in the list

Comment: Hmm I know for sure that the if statement does go through because the sendMessage happens. However it doesn't actually seem to remove the node from runtime or the XML file.

Comment: did you write back the xml into the file? the removal is only in memory

Answer (score 0):

since this is too large for comment, Here is my test code and results:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C://Temp/xx.xml"))) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xml = builder.parse(new InputSource(is));

        NodeList rootNodes = xml.getElementsByTagName("jobs");
        Node rootNode = rootNodes.item(0);
        Element rootElement = (Element) rootNode;
        NodeList jobsList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("job");

        System.out.println("list before removal");
        for (int i = 0; i < jobsList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node job = jobsList.item(i);
            Element jobElement = (Element) job;
            System.out.println(jobElement.getAttribute("id"));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < jobsList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node job = jobsList.item(i);
            Element jobElement = (Element) job;

            if (jobElement.getAttribute("id").equals("1")) {
                rootNode.removeChild(job);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("list after removal");
        jobsList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("job");
        for (int i = 0; i < jobsList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node job = jobsList.item(i);
            Element jobElement = (Element) job;
            System.out.println(jobElement.getAttribute("id"));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:

```
list before removal
1
2
list after removal
2
```